# How to get `docker login` read credentials from pass directly?

Tags: docker

I have successfully configured docker login to use `pass`[0][1] through its helper. The way it work is calling `docker login` asks me for username and password and then it stores the password in `pass` (so I can query it by `pass show docker-credential-helpers/aHR0cHM6Ly9pbmRleC5kb2NrZXIuaW8vdjEv/USERNAME`).

However, I already use `pass` to store the credential for me (`pass show hub.docker.com/USERNAME`). So at first I have to pull the password from the clipboard and then I can paste it to `docker login` that will store it thereof under different key.

Now, since the passwords are the same and both operations require me to unlock the credential store, is there a way to point `docker login` to the pass key I use to store the password so it can read it from there to avoid the annoying and potentially dangerous copy&paste?

- [0] https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
- [1] https://www.passwordstore.org/